# PowerShell script "Get-VMHost Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo" will return 2 values for the service tag

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine, vmware

I have the following power-shell script, where i want to get the ServiceTag for our servers:-

```
((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue
```

But i have noted that for some servers I will get 2 values representing the service tag, so is this normal? if so then which one i can use to identify the server?

**EDIT**
when i run this script:-

```
((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue
foreach ($vmhost in Get-VMHost) {
    $ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo; $ServiceTag | Get-Member

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ServiceTag)) { $ServiceTag = 'N/A' }

    Write-Host "$($vmhost.Name) - $ServiceTag"
}
```

I got this :-

```
Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Equals          Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType         Method     type GetType()
ToString        Method     string ToString()
DynamicProperty Property   VMware.Vim.DynamicProperty[] DynamicProperty {get;set;}
DynamicType     Property   string DynamicType {get;set;}
IdentifierType  Property   VMware.Vim.ElementDescription IdentifierType {get;set;}
IdentifierValue Property   string IdentifierValue {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

*This is actually a comment, but because it needs to be formatted in multiple lines I have added it as if an answer*

What happens if you do

```
foreach ($vmhost in Get-VMHost) {
    $ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | 
                  Where-Object { $_.IdentifierType.Key -eq "ServiceTag"}

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ServiceTag)) { $ServiceTag = 'N/A' }

    Write-Host "$($vmhost.Name) - $ServiceTag"
}
```

It appears the above does not return a string with the service tag, but an object. That object has a `IdentifierValue` property and that holds the string with the actual service tag. So we need to go one step deeper:

```
foreach ($vmhost in Get-VMHost) {
    $ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | 
                  Where-Object { $_.IdentifierType.Key -eq "ServiceTag"}

    if (($ServiceTag) -and $ServiceTag.IdentifierValue) { 
        $ServiceTag = $ServiceTag.IdentifierValue
    }

    Write-Host "$($vmhost.Name) - $ServiceTag"
}
```

---

**Edit**

It seems when obtaining Serial Numbers from Physical Servers, you'll have to deal with the ways hardware vendors expose these attributes. Different vendors treat them differently.

The various code you already tried returns two values for `IdentifierValue`. 
This occurs because the hardware vendor, (like Cisco) presents serial numbers per Processor.

Found that [here](http://markvcp.blogspot.com/).

*scroll down to the **ESXi Physical Servers** chapter*

Comment: i got something as follow `W************ - VMware.Vim.HostSystemIdentificationInfo VMware.Vim.HostSystemIdentificationInfo` so what does this indicate? that the server has 2 identification info ??

Comment: Ah, it seems that since VI API 2.5 the command returns an object rather than a plain string. If i read [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/vi-sdk/visdk250/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.SystemIdentificationInfo.html) correctly, you need to dig a bit deeper and get the `identifierValue`, so `$ServiceTag.identifierValue`. Try `$ServiceTag | Get-Member` to see what the command returns.

Comment: so you mean i need to modify my query as follow `$ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | Get-Member |
              Where-Object { $_.IdentifierType.Key -eq "ServiceTag"}` is so .. then this will return something as follow `W************ - N/A`

Comment: no, i meant test what you get with `$ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo; $ServiceTag | Get-Member`. If it is indeed an object, you should see the `identifierValue` property in there.

Comment: can you please check my edit .. i provided the outcome of running `$ServiceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo; $ServiceTag | Get-Member`

Comment: So, there is your answer then. Use `$ServiceTag.IdentifierValue` instead of just `$ServiceTag` and you should get the service tag you are after.

Comment: can you please advice how i need to use `$ServiceTag.IdentifierValue` i tried to print this value as follow `Write-Host "$($vmhost.Name) - $ServiceTag.IdentifierValue"` but i got `W********** - VMware.Vim.HostSystemIdentificationInfo VMware.Vim.HostSystemIdentificationInfo.IdentifierValue`

Comment: Try the edited answer or do `Write-Host "$($vmhost.Name) - $($ServiceTag.IdentifierValue)"`

Comment: ok i got 2 service tags numbers as follow `W******1 - C8****NA*****3 E1*****B0****`.. so this means the server has 2 service tags??.. those numbers are the same as the ones i received using my original code `((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue` which i am retrieving the service tag from using c#..

Comment: ok i tried your updated script,, but still i will get 2 service tags numbers as follow `W******* - C8888AA88NA8888 E7777777B77777`.. so this means the server has 2 service tags??.. those numbers are the same as the ones i received using my original code `((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue` which i am retrieving the service tag from using c#.. so do i have 2 service tags for the server or the server tag is actually constructed of two strings as follow `C8888AA88NA8888 E7777777B77777` ??

Comment: Sorry, still puzzled by that one, but [here](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.com/2014/11/powercli-vmhost-esxi-server-inventory.html) I found something that may help you. It uses this code `$serviceTag = $vmhost.ExtensionData.summary.hardware.otheridentifyinginfo | select-object -ExpandProperty IdentifierValue -last 1` so apparently if `IdentifierValue` has more than one value, you should use the last one. Hope this helps..

Comment: Also, see the **Edit** part of the answer

Comment: thanks a lot for your edits and comments. now i modify my code to always select the last service tag, in-case the server has more than one service tag.. but we have 300 servers, and for 12 servers i have noted that each server got 2 service tags.. the first tag is a unique number, while the second tag for the 12 servers is the same and equal `1234567890`.. now i modify my code to always select the second tag,, so does this mean that the service tags for the 12 server are `1234567890` and not the unique numbers which are retried as the first tag ??

Comment: This is a bit of a dilemma. I'm inclined to go for the first unique value if the second one is always the same. 
What does it say if you log in to the vSphere client -> click on the top level node in the left-hand tree structure (this is the vmware node) -> click on the "Configuration" tab -> On the left side, it will display "Hardware" and "Software" sections -> click on "Processors" link in the "Hardware" section -> under the "System", it should show the service tag. If there is only one listed there, I think you should accept that one for the result you want.

Comment: i am not sure about this to be honest... so some servers will have 1 service tag where i select this single service tag. other servers will have 2 unique services tags, where i select the second service tag. but 12 servers have 2 service tags, first one is unique number, while the other is `1234567890`.. but i read many articles + the ink you provided which mentioned that we should select the second service tag in-case the server has multiple service tags.. so does this mean that i have 12 servers with service tags = `1234567890`??

Comment: This is really taking a bit too long.
Hardware vendors may treat servicetags differently and that is why you can have more than one servicetag.
One I think is the servicetag of the Chassis, the other is the one you want to filter out.
There can be multiple vm servers on the same hardware, so for them the chassis number wil not change.

The problem here is not that they CAN have more than one number in the `IdentifierValue`, the thing is that you want to make sure you get the number for the VM server only.
To decide you need to get info per hardware vendor to figure out which is which.